# metric projection onto one dimensional (closed ) subspace in $L_p (p\neq 2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I want to know "if the metric projection onto one dimensional (closed) subspace in $L_p (p\neq 2)$ is linear? I think it is not linear, but I can not give a strict proof.

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! How did you come to the conclusion? It helps to add those details as that might be as important to answering the question. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider space $\mathbb{R}_1^2$ and its one dimensional subspace $X=\{(t,t): t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ the distance from $(a,0)$ to $X$ is given by
$$
d((0,a), X)
=\min_{x\in X} d((a,0), x)
=\min_{t\in\mathbb{R}}d((a,0),(t,t))
=\min_{t\in\mathbb{R}}(|a-t|+|t|)
$$
You can see that this function is minimized when $t\in[0,a]$. Hence solution of this minimization problem is not unique. So you can not even define metric projection, not to mention its linearity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do hope there are some examples in $L_p (p\neq 2)$.

Comment: By strict convexity there is a unique point that minimizes the distance for $1 \lt p \lt \infty$, so you can define a nearest point projection. The issue is its linearity if $p \neq 2$.

Comment: @Martin  fixed $\phantom{}$

Comment: Well, that was a cheap fix :-) I don't think it actually answers the question since it leaves the more interesting cases $p \neq 1,2, \infty$ open. However, since OP seems satisfied, I won't insist...

Comment: @Martin I thought a little, it is linear. If you want I can write the proof

Comment: Thanks, that won't be necessary. If you look at $\mathbb{R}^3_{p+1}$ with odd integer $p \geq 3$ you can see that the projection onto the diagonal line $(t,t,t)$ is not linear. The preimage of $(0,0,0)$ under the nearest point projection is the surface given by $x^p + y^p + z^p = 0$ which is not a linear subspace.

Comment: @Martin It seems that there should be not $x^p+y^p+z^p=0$ but $|x|^p+|y|^p+|z|^p=0$. Right?

Comment: No, that would be the origin only. The point of choosing $p$ odd is that $|x|^{p+1} = x^{p+1}$ which makes the formula very easy. But with a little care the same example works for any $1 \lt p \lt \infty$ and if $p \neq 2$ you see that the preimage of the origin under projection is not a linear subspace.

Comment: I see, thank you for your comments